# Adding an image to a rectangle with a gradient border

Tags: html, css

Hello I'm trying to make a series of windows with icons as the background but my current css looks like this for each rectangle but whenever i add the icon into the div it will not appear ever. Any suggestions?

```
`    margin:30px;
    padding-bottom: 15%;
/*
    border-width: 1px;
    border: solid;
    border-color: -webkit-linear-gradient(left, #4100db 0%,#3b128e 24%);
    border-radius: 5px;
    color: #FFF;
    */
    box-shadow: 0 4px 8px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2), 0 6px 20px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.19);


    border-left: 2px solid #384395;
    border-right: 2px solid #6F3B97;
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    background-position: 0 0, 0 100% ;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    -webkit-background-size: 100% 2px;
    -moz-background-size: 100% 2px;
    background-size: 100% 2px;
    background-image: url(data:image/svg+xml;base64,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),url(data:image/svg+xml;base64,PD94bWwgdmVyc2lvbj0iMS4wIiA/PjxzdmcgeG1sbnM9Imh0dHA6Ly93d3cudzMub3JnLzIwMDAvc3ZnIiB3aWR0aD0iMTAwJSIgaGVpZ2h0PSIxMDAlIiB2aWV3Qm94PSIwIDAgMSAxIiBwcmVzZXJ2ZUFzcGVjdFJhdGlvPSJub25lIj48bGluZWFyR3JhZGllbnQgaWQ9Imxlc3NoYXQtZ2VuZXJhdGVkIiBncmFkaWVudFVuaXRzPSJ1c2VyU3BhY2VPblVzZSIgeDE9IjAlIiB5MT0iMCUiIHgyPSIxMDAlIiB5Mj0iMCUiPjxzdG9wIG9mZnNldD0iMCUiIHN0b3AtY29sb3I9IiMzYWNmZDUiIHN0b3Atb3BhY2l0eT0iMSIvPjxzdG9wIG9mZnNldD0iMTAwJSIgc3RvcC1jb2xvcj0iIzNhNGVkNSIgc3RvcC1vcGFjaXR5PSIxIi8+PC9saW5lYXJHcmFkaWVudD48cmVjdCB4PSIwIiB5PSIwIiB3aWR0aD0iMSIgaGVpZ2h0PSIxIiBmaWxsPSJ1cmwoI2xlc3NoYXQtZ2VuZXJhdGVkKSIgLz48L3N2Zz4=);
    background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(left, #384395 0%, #6F3B97 100%), -webkit-linear-gradient(left, #384395 0%, #6F3B97 100%);
    background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(left, #384395 0%, #3a4ed5 100%), -moz-linear-gradient(left, #384395 0%, #6F3B97 100%);
    background-image: -o-linear-gradient(left, #384395 0%, #6F3B97 100%), -o-linear-gradient(left, #384395 0%, #6F3B97 100%);
    background-image: linear-gradient(to right, #384395 0%, #6F3B97 100%), linear-gradient(to right, #384395 0%, #6F3B97 100%);

`
```

Comment: Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself** preferably in a [**Stack Snippet**](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/).  See [**How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: You are overriding the icon image with the gradient, if you want to use multiple images separate them with a comma: `background: image1, image2, image3;`...

Comment: @Aziz so how would the gradient be retained? what would i need to reconstruct for this to work